# How to change column heading in WooCommerce "My account" orders table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

How can I change the column header text in recent order table in WooCommerce?

See attached image

[image]

The `myaccount/my-orders.php` template file in my theme contains:

```
<?php
/**
 * My Orders - Deprecated
 *
 * @deprecated 2.6.0 this template file is no longer used. My Account shortcode uses orders.php.
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$my_orders_columns = apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns',
    array(
        'order-number'  => esc_html__( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ),
        'order-date'    => esc_html__( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ),
        'order-status'  => esc_html__( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'order-total'   => esc_html__( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ),
        'order-actions' => '&nbsp;',
    )
);

$customer_orders = get_posts(
    apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query',
        array(
            'numberposts' => $order_count,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
            'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
        )
    )
);

if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', esc_html__( 'Recent orders', 'woocommerce' ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></h2>

    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) :
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
                ?>
                <tr class="order">
                    <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <td class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                /* translators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items */
                                printf( _n( '%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );

                                if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
                                    foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                                        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see at the top of the template file included in your question, it is deprecated since WooCommerce 2.6.0 and no longer used.

- My Orders - Deprecated since 2.6.0. This template file is no longer used. My Account shortcode uses `orders.php`

---

If you then have a look at [myaccount/orders.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/19eef38a3930e494bbd673714711338f11438253/templates/myaccount/orders.php) and [includes/wc-account-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/wc-account-functions.php) you will see it contains at line [186 - 206](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/wc-account-functions.php#L186-L206)

```php
/**
 * Get My Account > Orders columns.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 * @return array
 */
function wc_get_account_orders_columns() {
    $columns = apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_account_orders_columns',
        array(
            'order-number'  => __( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ),
            'order-date'    => __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ),
            'order-status'  => __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ),
            'order-total'   => __( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ),
            'order-actions' => __( 'Actions', 'woocommerce' ),
        )
    );

    // Deprecated filter since 2.6.0.
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', $columns );
}
```

---

So to answer your question:

Via the `woocommerce_account_orders_columns` filter hook you could apply this in the following way

```
function filter_woocommerce_account_orders_columns( $columns ) {
    // DEBUG: remove afterwards
    echo '<pre>', print_r( $columns, 1 ), '</pre>';
    
    $columns['order-number'] = __( 'New name 1', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['order-date'] = __( 'New name 2', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['order-status'] = __( 'New name 3', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['order-total'] = __( 'New name 4', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['order-actions'] = __( 'New name 5', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'filter_woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in your function.

```
function filter_woocommerce_account_orders_columns( $columns ) {
    
$columns['order_number'] = __( 'New name 1', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['order_date'] = __( 'New name 2', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['order_status'] = __( 'New name 3', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['order_total'] = __( 'New name 4', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['order_actions'] = __( 'New name 5', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'filter_woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 10, 1 );
```